# How do I create a new module in django and register the classes in that module

Tags: python, django, python-module

I want to create a new module and set of middleware classes in my app.  I created a subfolder "middleware" and put my python classes there in separate files.  But when I try to access them it says not defined.

For the following to work where do I place my 'CustomerMiddleware' class and what else do I need to do?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'dose.middleware.CustomMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to import them?  eg, from myapp.customclasses.file1 import class1

Comment: Yes sure.  I created a CustomMiddleware class located in a middlware.py file under my /dose/ app folder.   In mysite/settings.py I added  to MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'dose.middleware.CustomMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Comment: I expanded the original question

Answer (score 0):

Place your middleware at the end of your middleware section

The exact reference will depend on where the files live in your directory structure, relative to your projectfolder.  I keep mine in the same folder as my base URLs.py and asgi/wsgi files, so mine looks like the below

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'dose.middleware.CustomMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'projectname.middleware_filename.middlewareclass1',
'projectname.middleware_filename.middlewareclass2',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find a way to subclass a core Django class so I could change its behavior.  I found out how to do it, but along the way I discovered the Django Middleware that could intercept requests and responses anywhere in the application regardless of the app.  A CustomMiddleware was the key and with that I can do anything I want to do either before or after a request is handled by the model.

[Here is the Middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/)

Enjoy.